# Process external files over HTTPS inside XSLT2

Tags: java, https, xslt, saxon

I use the unparsed-text function to analyse external files in XSLT. This works well for HTTP-Urls. But when trying to load via HTTPS it fails. First I tried to put the credentials inside the URL, login and password (with or without URLEncoding, necessary for passwords with special chars) are assigned via parameters to XSLT (from JAVA code using Saxon HE 9.3.0.5 library). Result:

> XTDE1170: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL

The URL is correct inside any browser and will show the file. The certificate of the server is imported via keytool (without this another error message appears...)

My next attempt involves external Libraries as

> http://www.fgeorges.org/xslt/saxon-ext/#http

resulting in

> Error in call to extension function {public static net.sf.saxon.om.NodeInfo     org.fgeorges.xslt.Exslt2.httpSend(net.sf.saxon.expr.XPathContext,net.sf.saxon.om.NodeInfo,java.lang.String) throws net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException}: Exception in extension function java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is another element?!? - There is another element?!?

(...beats me...)

and

> http://www.expath.org/modules/http-client/

where it is impossible for me to import it with

```
<xsl:import href="http://expath.org/ns/http-client.xsl"/>
```

beacause the referenced file simply doesn't exisit...

End of all my wisdom... ;)
Any ideas?

Thanks and cheers!

Answer (score 0):

have you successfully installed the expath-saxon package as described in [this post (last paragraphs)](http://fgeorges.blogspot.com/2009/11/expath-packaging-system-on-disk.html#links)  ? apparently the xsl file only references the java implementation of the overloaded send-request methods, so you might only need some .xsl along the lines of `expath-http-client-saxon/xsl/expath-http-client-saxon.xsl` from [this archive](http://cxan.org/file/http-client-saxon/http-client-saxon-0.8.0.xar).

hope that helps,

best regards,

carsten